# Gitlab on docker: how to deal with dynamic IP?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, docker-network

I have a gitlab service on docker which uses `docker-compose up` command. The website can be accessed through something like: http://10.34.157.92:10080/

However, the host IP is not fixed but dynamic, so when the IP changes the website becomes something like http://10.34.241.138:10080/

I tried to edit `GITLAB_HOST` as `localhost` in `docker-compose.yml` but still in vain:

```
- GITLAB_HOST=localhost
- GITLAB_PORT=10080
- GITLAB_SSH_PORT=10022
...
...
```

Is there solution to this issue and let all users can access gitlab with fixed url? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you in a cloud environment like AWS, Azure, or GCP?  In AWS I'd use a load balancer and a Route 53 DNS name to give a consistent host name to the service; you should be able to do something similar in other environments.

Answer (score 0):

**Try exposing port 10080 with the following change in docker-compose file**

```
ports:
      - 10080:10080
```

And after that restart your docker-container and try connecting on localhost:10080, from the same machine where your container is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't have a fixed ipv4 address you'll have to use a [dynamic dns service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS).

These services are usually paid. There is a [list of such services at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_managed_DNS_providers).

It is often cheaper to rent a VPS with a fixed ipv4.